# Use devise for a model other than user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So, I am somewhat new to rails and devise, so I apologize in advance if this is a basic question.  I couldn't find any information on this anywhere, and I searched thoroughly.  This also makes me wonder if Devise is the right tool for this, but here we go:

I have an app where devise user authentication works great, I got it, implemented it correctly and it works.

In my app, users can belong to a group, and this group has a password that a user must enter to 'join' the group.

I successfully added `devise :database_authenticatable` to my model, and when I create it an encrypted password is created.

My problem, is that I cannot authenticate this!  I have a form where the user joins the group, searching for their group, then entering the password for it.

This is what I tried:

```
def join
    @home = Home.find_for_authentication(params[:_id]) # method i found that devise uses

    if @home.valid_password?(params[:password]);
      render :json => {success: true}
    else
      render :json => {success: false, message: "Invalid password"}
    end

end
```

This gives me the error: `can't dup NilClass`
on this line: `@home = Home.find_for_authentication(params[:_id])`

What is the problem?

Comment: What does find_for_authentication do? and what is join_params?

Comment: That is the internal method that devise uses to get a user before authenticating I believe. And join_params is just the parameters from my Ajax request

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs or stacktrace for further location the error?

Comment: This is it:
`TypeError (can't dup NilClass):
  app/models/home.rb:21:in `dup'
  app/models/home.rb:21:in `find_first_by_auth_conditions'
  app/controllers/api/v1/homes_controller.rb:9:in `join'
`

Essentially what I believe to be happening is the warden_conditions that the function needs is not getting passed to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be here:

```
Home.find_for_authentication(params[:_id])
```

I've never used `database_authenticatable` before (will research it, thanks!), so I [checked the Devise](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable) docs for you

---

The method they recommend:

```
User.find(1).valid_password?('password123')         # returns true/false
```

--

**Object?**

The method you've used [has a doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable/ClassMethods#find_for_authentication-instance_method):

> Find first record based on conditions given (ie by the sign in form).
>   This method is always called during an authentication process but it
>   may be wrapped as well. For instance, database authenticatable
>   provides a `find_for_database_authentication` that wraps a call to
>   this method. This allows you to customize both database
>   authenticatable or the whole authenticate stack by customize
>   `find_for_authentication.`
>
> Overwrite to add customized conditions, create a join, or maybe use a
>   namedscope to filter records while authenticating

The actual code looks like this:

```
def self.find_for_authentication(tainted_conditions)
  find_first_by_auth_conditions(tainted_conditions)
end
```

Looking at this code, it seems to me passing a single param is not going to cut it. You'll either need an object (hence `User.find([id])`), or you'll need to send a series of params to the method

I then found [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials):

```
class User
  def self.authenticate(username, password)
    user = User.find_for_authentication(:username => username)
    user.valid_password?(password) ? user : nil
  end
end
```

---

I would recommend doing this:

```
@home = Home.find_for_authentication(id: params[:_id])
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this didn't work before because I thought I tried it, but this is the code I ended up using and it works perfectly.

`def join
   @home = Home.find(join_params[:_id])

   if @home.valid_password?(join_params[:password]);
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @user.homes.push(@home)
    render :json => {success: true}
   else
    render :json => {success: false, message: "Invalid password"}
   end

  end`

`def join_params
   params.require(:home).permit(:_id, :password)
  end`

Comment: Nice so you used the first thing I found (find object & then use the `valid_password?` method)? :)

Comment: Yep, actually got it working last night, but looks like what you posted certainly would have worked as well, I didn't mention I am using mongoid as my backend which probably was important information.  Thanks for you help!